# How to visualize $(A\cap B)^\mathrm{o}=A^\mathrm{o} \cap B^\mathrm{o}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, intuition, visualization, motivation

We all know that

> $(A\cap B)^\mathrm{o}=A^\mathrm{o} \cap B^\mathrm{o}$, where $A,B \subset X$ which is a metric space.

The proof is not also difficult, but actually I cannot visualize or feel intuitively that this should happen.
Can someone provide me with an intuition that this is obvious even intuitively?
Some diagramatic representation is also welcome.

Comment: Sorry, what does the 0 superscript mean?

Comment: @AugSB interior of a set.

Comment: Draw to overlapping circles, representig A and B. Mark the intersection of A and B. Look at why it is true.

Comment: Try looking at it point by point. Check the neighbourhood of each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively:  This is intuitive so you *can't* quote or use it.

A set has an inside and an edge.  And the inside of a set is all the set minus the edge.

So $A\cap B$ is 1)Everything in both the inside of $A$ and then inside of $B$ plus 2) Everything in the inside of $A$ and the edge of $B$ and 3) Everything on the edge of $A$ and the inside of $B$ plus 4)  everything on the edge of $A$ and on the edge of $B$.

Now if $x$ is on the edge of $A$ then it's right next to things not in $A$ so it is right next to things not in $A\cap B$. So $x$ is either on the edge of $A\cap B$ or not in $A\cap B$ at all;  it certainly can't be that $x$ is on the *inside* of $A\cap B$.

And the same goes for $y$ on the edge of $B$.

In other words if any point is on the edge of $A$ or $B$ it's not on the inside of $A\cap B$.

So $(A\cap B)^\circ$, which is $A\cap B$ minus the edges of $A\cap B$ must strip away the edges of $A$ and $B$.

So $(A\cap B)^\circ$ can contain 1)Everything in both the inside of $A$ and then inside of $B$ **but not** 2) *Everything in the inside of $A$ and the edge of $B$* nor 3) *Everything on the edge of $A$ and the inside of $B$* and not 4)  *everything on the edge of $A$ and on the edge of $B$*.

So $(A\cap B)^\circ$ can only contain points in $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$.  But does it contain all of them?  If $y \in A^\circ \cap B^\circ$ then everything immediately around it is in $A$ and everything immediately around it is in $B$.  So everything immediately around it is in both $A$ and in $B$.

So $(A\cap B)^\circ$ consists only of and all of the points in $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$.

Comment: Anyone who quotes me on this and whoever uses the phrase "everything immediately around it" will be shot.

Comment: but why does $\bar{ (A\cap B)}$ not equal to $\bar A \cap \bar B$.